# Как прочитать сообщения из чужого потока stdout?

Tags: c

Ребят, возникла проблема: У меня есть две программы , одна(написанная не мной, пусть будет `пр1`) отправляет в поток сообщения, а другая(моя, `пр2`) должна прочитать эти сообщения из потока вывода. Но дело в том, что стандартные потоки присоединяются приложениям уникальные, то есть я не могу прочитать сообщения программы `пр1`? Перенаправить поток в файл я тоже не могу, т.к `пр1` написана не мной и доступа я к ней не имею. Может как-то можно решить эту проблему?
Босс убьет если не поможете, очень надеюсь на вашу помощь, мне и так платят едой.

Comment: Эм? `пр1 | пр2` не работает что ли?

Comment: @AlexeyTen ой, что то забыл про каналы

Comment: @AlexeyTen, удалять этот глупый вопрос, или вы напишете в ответе это и я его отмечу как правильный?

Comment: Ну тут все просто, удали лишению "гы" и все заработает

Comment: Зачем портить свой вопрос?

Comment: Пожалуйста, не создавайте лишнюю работу другим участникам, вандализируя собственные посты. При размещении сообщения на сайте «Stack Overflow на русском» вы даёте SO, в соответствии с лицензией [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.ru), неотзываемое право на распространение своего контента. В соответствии с политикой SO любые вандальные действия будут отменены. Если вы желаете узнать больше про удаление постов, пожалуйста, прочитайте ["Как работает удаление?"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2293/223536).

Comment: @AlexeyTen, ответ пиши.